# I implemented a google sign in in ios app. Now, how can I verify if user is logged in and if not - return him to the login page with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

As I wrote in the title of this question - I went through this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in and now I'm able to log in the user to my app based on his google credentials.

The way I do it so far is that I have a `ViewController.swift` class with the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
        background.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
        //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
        //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapSignOut(sender: AnyObject) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
        print("Nothing!")
    }

    // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
        presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
        dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and in my AppDelegate.swift class I have:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Initialize sign-in
            var configureError: NSError?
            GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
            assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

            return true
    }

    // [START openurl]
    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation)
    }
    // [END openurl]

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    }

    // [START signin_handler]
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {
            if (error == nil) {
                print("Signed in!")
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
    }
    // [END signin_handler]

    // [START disconnect_handler]
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {
            // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                "ToggleAuthUINotification",
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
}
```

My storyboard looks as follows:

[image]

On the left I have a `ViewController` with marked google button (which is white, therefore it's not visible here - sorry!) and on the right I have a main `TabController` view that contains the whole logic of my app (so far it's quite empty):

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
        background.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Now it works like this:

I run the app and see the google button to sign in. I sign in and when everything is validated - nothing changes, I'm not moving to the second screen (`TabController`). I just stay on this view and I can keep clicking the google button - nothing changes though because I'm already signed in.

I want to achieve a situation when the user opens my app and when he is not logged in - he sees the `ViewController` screen. When he logs in - he sees the `TabController` screen. And also when he already signed in before and opens my app - he immediately jumps to `TabController` and skips the `ViewController` page. How can I achieve it?

I suspect I have to mark on my storyboard my `TabController` to be the `initial view controller`, but what about the log in screen?

=====EDIT

following Mac Bellingrath answer I modified my function in `appDelegate.swift` class, now it looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        /* check for user's token */
        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
            /* Code to show your tab bar controller */
            print("user is signed in")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? UITabBarController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        } else {
            print("user is NOT signed in")
            /* code to show your login VC */
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as? ViewController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        }

        return true
}
```

Now when I run the app and the user has been signed in before - I see the `tabController` view. If he wasn't signed in before - I see the `ViewController` view. It works almost like a charm, but I realized that no matter if I write `if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {` or `if !GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {` it always prints out 
the message `user is signed in`, so something is still not right...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in), it appears that you can use GIDSignIn's instance method hasAuthInKeychain() to check whether the user has either currently signed in or has previous authentication saved in keychain.

So, in your AppDelegate's

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions                    launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

You might write something like:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
/* check for user's token */
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
/* Code to show your tab bar controller */
} else {
/* code to show your login VC */
}
```

for example if our user is signed in:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBarVC") as? UITabBarController {
window.rootViewController = tabBarVC
}
```

*Substitute your UITabBarController subclass for UITabBarController.

Of course, there are many ways to change the flow. Check out storyboard reference and multiple storyboards.

Comment: Ok, I took your logic and put it in my `Delegateapp`. It works, almost :). When I run the app and I'm signed in - that's great, I see the main `TabController` and skip the `ViewController`. When I'm not logged in and run the app I see the `ViewController` with a sign in button. I perform the sign in process and instead of going to `TabController` I'm back in `ViewController` and I cannot proceed to the `TabController` since the google login button does not do anything (since I'm already logged in). How can I fix it?

Comment: @randomuser1 have you verified that hasAuthKeychain() returns false after you log the user out?

Comment: @randomuser1 Also noticed that it looks like you aren't casting the UITabBarController to your subclass.

Comment: yes I checked that it returns false, so that's good message. Speaking about your next comment and casting - Can you give me some example how to do it? sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you meant about that :(

Comment: @randomuser1 cast to your TabController, not the stock UIKit ex -    if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController  {                 window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC             }         } else {             print("user is NOT signed in")             /* code to show your login VC */             let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)             if let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as? ViewController {                 window!.rootViewController = vc             }         }

Comment: Mac, thank you very much, now it's clear for me. I just need to handle the logout button, but I think I will ask another question about it here. Have a good one!

Answer (score 3):

```
let googleUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().isCurrentUser

if googleUser != nil {
// Get new token from google and send to server
let strToken = googleUser.authentication.idToken
} else {
// present login screen here
presentLoginScreen()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac Bellingrath given perfect answer for verify user is logged in.

Alternate way to check user logged in.

Here is sample code in Objective-C you can convert code as per your requirement.

This sample code is just for your reference.

```
    // The authentication object for the current user, or |nil| if there is currently no logged in user.
    // Here you can get current user object
    GIDGoogleUser *googleUser = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] currentUser];

    if (googleUser) {
        // Get new token from google and send to server
        NSString *strToken = googleUser.authentication.idToken;
    }
    else {
        // present login screen here
        [self presentLoginScreen];
    }
```

Comment: thanks! Does this mean I need to verify the token in the server for **every** protected request in my backend?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, If this answer is helpful for you please upvote my answer,

You can no need to verify token every time from your backend server.

Comment: cool, thanks for answering! So if I'm not sending the token from the front-end in every request, how can the server know the user is authenticated to access some protected endpoints?

Comment: If you need to authenticate with the server so you need to compare the token every time when user opens the application.

Comment: well... the token expires after 1hr, right? so I would have to authenticate the user every time an hour passes. Probably that's not the user experience I'm looking for, or maybe I'm missing something, not sure... I think Google OAuth2 is what I'm looking for then since I have both access token and refresh token